# Configure Basic Authentication on Azure's App Service

Tags: azure, http-basic-authentication

For different reasons I'm using `Azure's App Service` to serve static files. I would like to secure this access by `Http Basic Authentication` which is enough for my purposes. How can I do that? I tried uploading `.htpasswd` but it does not seem to work.

I'm not using ASP.NET so no way to do it in code. In Azure's portal I see options like Google, Facebook, Twitter login under App Service -> Authentication/Authorization but it's huge overhead for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible. Azure webapp does not support this.

You could check this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/12805239-allow-http-basic-authentication-on-basic-apps).

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to enable Basic Authentication for Azure Web Apps with some settings in the **applicationHost.xdt**. You can load some modules in this file on the start of your Web App.

**Steps:**

- Navigate to your WebApp in the Azure Portal
- In the left menu, search for the header **Development Tools** an select **Advanced Tools** (Kudu)
- Use the **Debug Console > CMD** tool, to navigate to the WebApp directory: **\home\site**
- Create a file named: **applicationHost.xdt**
- Paste the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <allowedServerVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
          <add name="RESPONSE_WWW_AUTHENTICATE" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
        </allowedServerVariables>
        <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
          <rule name="BasicAuthentication" stopProcessing="true" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION}" pattern="^Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="401" statusReason="Unauthorized" statusDescription="Unauthorized" />
            <serverVariables>
              <set name="RESPONSE_WWW_AUTHENTICATE" value="Basic realm=Project" />
            </serverVariables>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

- Change the Basic Auth to your liking (default in example is: user:password)
- Make sure the web.config rewrite rules don't contain `<clear />` as this wil remove the effects from the applicationHost.xdt file
- Save the file and Stop and Start your WebApp (a simple *Restart* will **not** suffice)

**Notes:**

- Not sure if this works on Linux based WebApps..
- You can add this step to you're deployment pipelines by using FTP
- **Update:** I've noticed issues with applicationHost.xdt while using it on secondary Web App slots. Only the primary slot seems to work.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on Linux app service plan

Comment: This is the correct answer. Should be marked as such. This answer also contains more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70103415/hi-how-do-i-change-this-applicationhost-xdt-to-use-a-custom-username-password

Answer (score 2):

Basic Authentication is not currently supported within Azure Web Apps via the Azure Portal.

However DevBridge provides an module which allows Basic Authentication to be enabled.

https://www.alexlindgren.com/posts/password-protect-azure-website-with-basic-authentication/

https://www.alexlindgren.com/posts/password-protecting-azure-websites-revisited/

https://www.devbridge.com/articles/basic-authentication-for-windows-azure-websites/

**Source code**
https://github.com/devbridge/AzurePowerTools/tree/master/Devbridge.BasicAuthentication