# Basic Authentication for an Azure Web App based on Linux

Tags: linux, azure, http-basic-authentication, azure-web-apps

I have an Azure Web App based on Linux. I want to enable basic authentication, meaning that it simply asks for a username and password in the header to access the web app.

I've only found a solution ([Configure Basic Authentication on Azure's App Service](https://serverfault.com/questions/901508/configure-basic-authentication-on-azures-app-service)) that applies if the app is based on Windows, where you create an applicationHost.xdt file through CMD, but this doesn't work on Linux.

I expect something like this:
[image]

Comment: Please rephrase this into a question and provide more information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to configure nginx via console for a appservice linux

In a azure portal use Tools->SSH

1. install apache2-utils for use htpassw
   apt install apache2-utils

2 create one o more user and password
htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd test

3 modify site-default /admin it will be the protected directory
(/home/site/wwwroot/admin)

nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

location /admin {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
auth_basic "admin area";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}

4 service nginx restart
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPLHi.jpg)